# Prepending a dynamic 'a' tag to the 'li' elements with a certain class

Tags: jquery, wordpress

Please take a look at the code below:

```
<ul id="all-movies">                    
  <li class="movie">
    <img src="pic.jpg" />
  </li>
  <li class="movie featured">
    <img src="pic.jpg" />
  </li>
  <li class="movie featured">
    <img src="pic.jpg" />
  </li>
</ul>
```

In the code above, I would like to prepend `<a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/hello"></a>` to the `li` elements with a class of `featured` so that it looks like this:

```
<ul id="all-movies">                    
  <li class="movie">
    <img src="pic.jpg" />
  </li>
  <li class="movie featured">
    <a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/hello"></a>
    <img src="pic.jpg" />
  </li>
  <li class="movie featured">
    <a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/hello"></a>
    <img src="pic.jpg" />
  </li>
</ul>
```

And `<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>` will be replaced with my site.

How can I get this to work? I have tried something like the following but it didn't work:

`$("#all-movies li").hasClass('featured').prepend('<a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/hello"></a>');`

Note: The `featured` class is being added dynamically.

-edit- This is the code I'm using to add the `featured` class dynamically:

```
function wpse80098_filter_post_class( $classes ) {
    global $post;
    if ( 'yes' == get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_jsFeaturedPost', true ) ) {
        $classes[] = 'featured';
    }
    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'post_class', 'wpse80098_filter_post_class' );
```

Comment: Is this going to work? Even when you get the prepend working, wont it be too late for the page to render the PHP? PHP is done server side and by the time you are at the prepend, the request is already on the client. You will probaly need to store bloginfo('url') in a local javascript variable (var blogInfo = "<?= bloginfo('url') ?>";), then use that in your prepend.

Comment: Dynamically added classes shouldn't be a problem, as long as they are added before you try to add the `<a>`s to them.

Comment: If `featured` is being added dynamically, why not just use the same code to add the `bloginfo('url')` in the php file?

Comment: @Sandor If it's not too much trouble, can you help me with that? I added the code I'm using in the post above.

Comment: @John which wordpress theme are you using?

Comment: @Sandor It's a custom one I'm building.

Comment: @John great, can you add the code which renders the list `all-movies` or just the code which renders a single `<li>` to the question, I assume that it has a `<li <?php post_class(); ?>>` which has your filter attached to it at some point?

Answer (score 1):

`hasClass` returns a boolean value which doesn't have `prepend` method, you can use class selector.

```
$("#all-movies li.featured").prepend('<a href="<?php bloginfo("url"); ?>/hello"></a>');
```

or:

```
$("#all-movies li").filter('.featured').prepend('<a href="<?php bloginfo("url"); ?>/hello"></a>');
```

Comment: I tried both of these but they don't work. I think it's because the `featured` class is being added dynamically via function.php. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: @John Have you put your code within document ready handler? `$(document).ready(function(){  })`

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var yourURL = "<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/hello";
    $("#all-movies li.featured").prepend('<a href="'+yourURL+'"></a>');
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try out with `.find()` function:

```
var url = "<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/hello";
$('ul#all-movies').find('li.featured').prepend("<a href='"+url+"'></a>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
$("#all-movies li.featured").prepend('<a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/hello"></a>');
```

Thats assuming the `<?php ?>` stuff is actually processed on your server and doesn't make its way to the client.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('li.featured').each(function(){
   $(this).prepend('<a href="<?php bloginfo("url"); ?>/hello"></a>');
});
```