# dynamically prepend 'a' tag to posts with 'featured' classes. 'featured' class is being dynamically added too

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm using the code below to dynamically add a class `featured` to the posts with a meta_value of `yes`. Additionally, I need to prepend `<a href="<?php bloginfo("url"); ?>/about"></a>` to the posts that have the `featured` class. Is there any way I can add something to this code to achieve this?

```
function wpse80098_filter_post_class( $classes ) {
    global $post;
    if ( 'yes' == get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_jsFeaturedPost', true ) ) {
        $classes[] = 'featured';
    }
    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'post_class', 'wpse80098_filter_post_class' );
```

Right now, the HTML looks like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <p>hello</p>
  </li>
  <li class="featured">
    <p>hello</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I want the HTML to look like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <p>hello</p>
  </li>
  <li class="featured">
    <a href="<?php bloginfo("url"); ?>/about"></a>
    <p>hello</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

With `<?php bloginfo("url"); ?>` of course being replaced by my site.

If I can't add to the code, what other ways could I go about doing this?

Comment: What function renders the HTML?

Comment: Is the href always the same? If not, then to do this client-side would require the url to be encoded into the HTML, therefore you might as well build the whole thing server-side. Clent-side solution only seems viable if the url was always the same but that would be crazy.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14273096/prepending-a-dynamic-a-tag-to-the-li-elements-with-a-certain-class

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot It's always the same, because bloginfo('url') is the URL to the front page of the website.

Comment: (a) can you successfully add the `featured` class? (b) is this done on initial page build or on returning an HTML snippet via AJAX?

Comment: As @Calle says, this is a duplicate. I'm outa here.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot Yes, I can successfully add the `featured` class. Sorry about the duplicates but I felt this one was a different direction which deserved its own thread. Sorry if I broke rules...

Answer (score 0):

Add below code for prepend the url.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var URL = "<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/hello";
    $("li.featured").prepend('<a href="'+yourURL+'"></a>');
});
</script>
```